# Accumulating gradient in pytorch using multiple process

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, pytorch, multiprocessing

I am working on a model which is relatively simple and small. (1000-10,000 parameters max).
Since there are not so many parameters, training the model is simple and does not consume much time. The data loading part is the bottleneck.

To make the training faster my plan is to spawn `n` threads, each of which load a small chunk of data -> do the forward pass -> compute likelihood -> do backwards pass to store gradients -> all `n` process combine the gradients to do a single `optimizer.step()`

Please note that the reason I don't do a Stochastic Gradient Descent is that the problem statement requires me to work with true gradients which can only be obtained by computing the gradient for the whole dataset.
Also, I **cannot** load the whole data into memory because of size constraints and I have to load in chunks(Although I can have multiple such processes loading these chunks).

Pytorch does provide a resource of [Multiprocessing](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html) which has the following skeleton code listed in it.

```
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from model import MyModel

def train(model):
    # Construct data_loader, optimizer, etc.
    for data, labels in data_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_fn(model(data), labels).backward()
        optimizer.step()  # This will update the shared parameters

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_processes = 4
    model = MyModel()
    # NOTE: this is required for the ``fork`` method to work
    model.share_memory()
    processes = []
    for rank in range(num_processes):
        p = mp.Process(target=train, args=(model,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

In order to make sure this works, I wrote a simple linear regression test which makes sure that the output of a model trained using multiple processes and a model trained using a single process, is the same.

```
import random

import torch.multiprocessing as mp
import torch.optim
from torch import nn
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm



class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.theta = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(1.0, dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True))
        self.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(1.0, dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float)
        return self.theta*x + self.bias


loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()

random.seed(42)


def f_x(x):
    # return 3*x + 4 + random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1)
    return 3*x + 4


def train(model, optimizer, x, y):
    # Construct data_loader, optimizer, etc.
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    out = model(x)
    loss = loss_fn(out, torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.float))
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()  # This will update the shared parameters


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model_multi_process = MyModel()
    model_single_process = MyModel()
    optimizer_multi_process = torch.optim.SGD(model_multi_process.parameters(), lr=0.01)
    optimizer_single_process = torch.optim.SGD(model_single_process.parameters(), lr=0.01)
    inputs = [2, 4, 6, 10]
    fx = list(map(f_x, inputs))
    num_processes = 4
    # NOTE: this is required for the ``fork`` method to work
    model_multi_process.share_memory()
    processes = []
    epochs = 10
    for _ in tqdm(range(epochs)):
        for rank, x, y in zip(range(num_processes), inputs, fx):
            p = mp.Process(target=train, args=(model_multi_process, optimizer_multi_process, x, y))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)
        for p in processes:
            p.join()

        for x, y in zip(inputs, fx):
            train(model_single_process, optimizer_single_process, x, y)

    print(model_multi_process(1))
    print(model_single_process(1))
    print(f_x(1))
```

I have **2 questions** about this.

1.) **The out for both the models (i.e. *model_multi_process* and *model_single_process*) is not the same(and moreover the multi_process_model doesn't seem to be converging at all), why is it so?**

2.) **Is there a pytorch/python way to do 1 single optimizer.step with the true gradients while computing the gradients in multiple processes?**

Thanks in advance and feel free to ask any follow-up questions if something is not clear.

Cheers!